# Azure DevOps - Branch's behind and ahead count will get reset after successful PR

Tags: azure-devops, compare, branch, behind

The ahead and behind numbers listed for each branch will get reset or remain same after successful pull request to compare branch?
[Azure DevOps ahead and behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAam1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ahead and behind numbers listed for each branch will get reset or remain same after successful pull request to compare branch?

According to the document [Manage branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops#change-the-compare-branch)：

> The ahead and behind numbers listed for each branch are in comparison
> with the branch currently labeled **Compare** on the Branches page.

The ahead and behind numbers are related to the branch that is set to be compared.

So, when we merge the commit to the compare branch, the **behind listed** for each branch will get reset after successful pull request to compare branch. But only the **ahead** numbers for the **merged** branch will be reset to zero, and other branches will remain same.

For example:

[image]

After merged the branch `DevTest1` to `Dev` by PR:

[image]

The **behind listed** for each branch will get reset, only the **ahead** numbers for the **merged** branch will be reset to zero, and other branches will remain same.

Comment: Hi Leo Lie, Thank you for the response. After successful merge the ahead number for the merged branch didn't  reset to zero. Is merge type plays any role in count reset?

Comment: @user12238330, Yes, it is related to the merge type.

Comment: It looks like "DevTest2" branch "behind" num should change from 2 to 3 (not from 2 to 5), since the Dev branch (Compare branch) changed by one commit (after merging of DevTest1 to Dev), do I right?